# Icons for custom mime-type does not show up with Ubuntu-mono-dark theme

Tags: nautilus, themes, icons, mime-type

I manually installed [LuxRender 1.2.1](http://www.luxrender.net/en_GB/index) under `/usr/local/bin/` and it works fine and dandy. I then created 5 new mime-types for LuxRender `*.lxs`, `*.lxo`, `*.lxm`, `*.lxv` and `*.flm` file formats (scene, objects, materials, volumes and film). I created them with `assogiate` for convenience, however here is the simple generated `Override.html` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="text/x-luxrender-scene">
        <glob pattern="*.lxs"/>
        <comment>LuxRender Scene</comment>
    </mime-type>
    <mime-type type="text/x-luxrender-materials">
        <glob pattern="*.lxm"/>
        <comment>LuxRender Materials</comment>
    </mime-type>
    <mime-type type="text/x-luxrender-objects">
        <glob pattern="*.lxo"/>
        <comment>LuxRender Objects</comment>
    </mime-type>
    <mime-type type="text/x-luxrender-volumes">
        <glob pattern="*.lxv"/>
        <comment>LuxRender Volumes</comment>
    </mime-type>
    <mime-type type="image/x-luxrender-film">
        <glob pattern="*.flm"/>
        <comment>LuxRender Film</comment>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then, I ran `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime`, which updated the file `mime.cache`. The mime-types now works (both tested with `mimetype` and in the Nautilus properties panel of a file).

Now I want to associate the icons (which come with LuxRender as 256x256 png files). I resized them to the apropriate sizes and put them under `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/??x??/mimetypes`. Finally, i refreshed the cache with `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor`.

If I open `assogiate`, it displays the correct icons even if I haven't explicitly defined them. However, Nautilus does not.
Since I'm using *Ubuntu-mono-dark* (which however inherits from *hicolor*), I thought that it was because I had to put them under `/usr/share/icons/Ubuntu-mono-dark` too, or maybe `/usr/share/icons/Humanity`. However, this doesn't work neither.

The strange fact is that if I switch my theme to *hicolor*, the new icons actually shows up! This seems to suggest that they are installed correctly...

Does anyone have an idea about what is happening? Where do I have to put the icons? What should I configure?

PS: just as a side note, I had the same problem with Mathematica icons...

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. I installed them under `gnome`, `Humanity`, `Humanity-Dark`, `ubuntu-mono-dark`... and finally got it work. I really don't care to know how does this work...
It seems to me that the `Inherits=` line in `index.theme` does never fall back to `hicolor`.

Comment: Placing your custom icons into `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/` was enough.